# Displaying Wordpress posts in 2 columns using Bootstrap

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns, posts

I use bootstrap, and I would like to display my Wordpress posts in two columns on my index.php page. I show only the_permalink of my posts, and I would like to have them in horizontaly order.
When the page is loaded from xs screen, I'd like to have the posts in one column, on top of each other.
I tried many different things, but I couldn't get a proper php code. I started again from scratch, Here is the code I have for now:

```html
<?php if (have_posts()):  ?>

<div class="container">
  <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

  <div class="row">
    <div id="post_title_overview_page">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php $first = str_replace(' | ', '<br />', get_the_title()); echo str_replace('REPLACE_ME', '<i>REPLACE_ME</i>', $first);?></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>

<?php else: ?>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <p>no result</p>
  </div>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I would really appreciate your help! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The class that you are using is not correct. Use the following

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php $first = str_replace(' | ', '<br />', get_the_title()); echo str_replace('REPLACE_ME', '<i>REPLACE_ME</i>', $first);?></a>
      </div>
```

col-lg-* is used for larger screens

col-md-* is used for medium screens

col-xs-* is used for small screens

Since you want two div side by side on large devices so lg-6 is used and on small you only want one div so xs-12 is used

Comment: Hi siddharth, thank you for you answer. By doing lg-6, it only makes the div half size and still display the posts in one column. I would like to display the posts on two columns, do I have to add another div?

Comment: What screen you are working on. May be you have a medium screen. Did you try using col-md-6 class. There is no need to add another div. Give it a try using class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"

Comment: I am working on a large screen. lg-6 makes the width half smaller, it doesnt create 2 columns. What I would like is when I am positng articles, they show up in chronological order, in two columns. Any idea?